# is it possible to create dynamic animationstyle

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using the PopupWindow in Android to show several responses to the user.
Based on the choices the user made in the app/game, the PopupWindow should come on screen in different ways.

I figured to use the PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle to show the message, but it only takes an existing animationstyle ID.
Which means I would have to create an animation.xml file for every single animation, with location, duration etc set in the xml.
These can come from many left, right, top, bottom, even fade in/out and for many different durations

I was wondering/hoping if it's possible to either use variables (for duration and location etc.) but couldn't find any possible information on this subject.
Hence my asking here if it's possible to either create the xml in code, or use variables in the animation xml file.

Or perhaps even use some completely different method of animating a PopupWindow if that's how I can get it to work.

I appreciate any and all input, many thanks in advance.

Comment: In the end I kind of fixed it by animating the view inside the popupwidow, but now the animation is limited by the size of the popupwindow. Not exactly what I wanted but close enough I guess.